# First 80286 Based Computer

Tags: ibm-pc, 80286

The 80286 was released in early 1982. The IBM PC AT, which used it, was released in late 1984.

Two and a half years is a long time to design a new computer that is a fairly modest upgrade on existing technology, and a long time for new technology as commercially important as the 286 to go unused. I'm conjecturing that IBM felt they could take it easy because their PC already had technical superiority over the competition, but according to InfoWorld, in August 1982 there were already an estimated 60-70 companies with or working on PC clones; surely at least some of them must have felt the pressure.

Was there any computer, particularly but not limited to any PC clone, based on the 286 before the AT?

Comment: Just gonna chime in that 2 1/2 years isn't a lot of time to engineer a brand new product. It's not a casual upgrade to the PC. New motherboard, new processors, 3 times faster, new bus, new BIOS, new case, new keyboard, new floppy drive, etc. And this is back in the day when folks were still designing stuff with stone knives and bear skins, all of which affect time to market.

Comment: I would assume had they not targetted for a *modest upgrade of an existing computer* but rather an entirely new one without any compatibility, development could have been much faster.

Comment: @WillHartung Even back then a new computer could be done in a matter of several month, not years. Don't underestimate our 'forefathers' craftmanship. Woz designed the Apple II in under a year with *way* less resources than Intel or IBM had.

Comment: @Raffzahn And now you've highlighted the difference between a globe spanning, bazillion dollar corporation and a guy in a garage.

Comment: Is the MDK-286 in scope here?

Comment: @WillHartung - of course, the project that eventually produced the IBM 5150 PC was set up with the explicit goal of finding out whether a large globe spanning corporation could compete with the likes of Apple in rapid development.  They developed the first prototype in 30 days, and had the product in retail within a year, including sourcing OS and languages and finding manufacturing and retail partners (as IBM had never used either before, having done everything themselves historically).  I think they did quite well, considering...

Comment: "IBM felt they could take it easy because their PC already had technical superiority over the competition" The IBM PC didn't have technical superiority on the day it was first released.

Comment: @JeremyP How do you reckon? What other personal computer do you think was a match for the IBM PC in 1981?

Comment: @rwallace including or excluding deskside workstations ala PERQ, Xerox Alto and Star, Symbolics, Apollo?

Comment: @rackandboneman Excluding. 'The competition' means personal computers in roughly the same price bracket e.g. the Apple II and Commodore PET, not workstations costing many times as much.

Comment: It's easy to forget in this day and age where new CPU revisions are being barfed out every few months and immediately put into use in the newest generation of PCs, that processors didn't immediately go from lab to high street back in the day. The 6502 is possibly a notable exception, but it otherwise generally took at least a couple of years, if not longer, for a chip to go from being the new jewel-encrusted hotness... that no-one in the street can afford, and no-one in the industry yet knows how to program... to actually being something in a real, useful machine that an ordinary person could

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, one of the first will be for sure [Intels System 310/286](http://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102652384_[1]). According to the CHM this would be 1981, but I think it was rather 1982/83 - that would also fit the [original flyer](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_intelsysteGdeOct83_1335604/173441-001_310pubGde_Oct83#page/n0/mode/2up). It's a Multibus system using the iSBC 286/10 single board computer running Xenix. The board was also used by several other manufacturers for early 286 based Unix sytems and real time applications - way until the 1990s - Intel even added a revised [iSBC 286/10A](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/intel/iSBC/147532-001_iSBC_286_10A_Hardware_Reference_Manual_Oct84.pdf) in 1985 to satisfy demand. [Here a nice report](http://www.retrotechnology.com/herbs_stuff/386intel/i310_beech.html) about someone reviving a 310. When searching the net for more information, be aware that the system 310 was also/originaly available with a 8086 board.